Backtrader - Sizer class - position sizing for bracket orders where size is a function of the entry/stop gap in pips
I want to do proper position sizing based on my risk. I need to do that using a one sided bracket order with an entry order and a stop loss order.
With the entry and stop loss prices calculated, I can dynamically derive the pips of risk by knowing the entry and stop loss gap however the Sizer _getsizing() method does not let me pass risk which is an important factor of calculating a risk based position size.
Can anyone suggest a method of using the Sizer class for calculating a variable risk based position size?
I could add an argument 'risk' to the signature of the _getsizing() method that defaults to None.
I could add entry and stop arguments to _getsizing() method to calculate risk.
I've just used Sizer as a % or fixed. This doesn't allow me to back test my risk based strategy which is an important aspect.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
